# Simulate backslash keyboard keystroke

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

Basically I need to simulate a keyboard input. And I need to write a backslash. I can't install anything on this computer I need to rely entirely on win32com. I can write most characters but can't figure out  how to write a backslash. My keyboard has a french configuration.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Do you mean win32com from [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)? Both in tags and in the question title?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that what I meant.

Comment: To allow people to help better, please show the code how you are writing the other characters.